# What kind of power connector do Sony VAIO laptops use?

Tags: connector

I have a Sony VAIO laptop with a loose power connector. I'm not sure if the problem is with the female or the male connector. I want to replace it. How can I find out the type of the connector so I can buy a new one and replace it?

Comment: Without a schematic it can be very hard to identify connectors. However, for laptops you can often find various parts on eBay - search for "<your model number> power connector" or "vaio power jack" or similar, it's very likely you will find a replacement.

Comment: If you can't source one, then if it's a common footprint, you can probably replace it with one with the same footprint and change the jack if necessary. Search for "DC sockets" on Farnell, Mouser, Digiket, etc.

Comment: Have you searched on eBay? I did a quick search and it returned hundreds of results.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira - I thought it might (especially with it being a Vaio) I recently fixed a friends laptop which had a broken power connector with an odd footprint - after coming up with nothing elsewhere I found one on eBay no problem. There seem to replacement parts for just about every laptop on there, while we were at it we ordered a couple of keys that had broken off too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Most Sony Vaio laptops have a 19VDC power supply with a 9.5mm long shaft (OD=6mm ID=4,3mm) with inner pin through the centre which is the positive terminal.

http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/cat-vaio/cat-vaioaccessories/?navId=4294963397+4294963245&refine=4294967294

Answer (score 0):

Almost all are as noted above

Some like the VPCF126fm have a jack with two central pins that can work with long pin plugs but feel very loose and have to be in a certain position to charge. I just bought such a laptop with out knowing that. It uses a 19.5 volt, 6.1amp.

You can visually see if the jack inside the computer has two coper shafts or else.